# Minimum number of twin primes < N

Tags: nt.number-theory

I saw that someone had calculated an upper bound for the number of twin primes less than a given integer N.

It is obvious that if we can calculate a lower bound for the number of twin primes less than a given integer N, and that lower bound goes to infinity as N goes to infinity,
then we have proven that there are infinitely many twin primes.

What research has been done in this direction?

Kermit Rose

Comment: Opera de Cribro, by Friedlander and Iwaniec, is an excellent recent book dealing with this family of problems. You might also see the book by Cojocaru and Murty for a gentler introduction.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299011/a-formula-that-counts-exactly-the-twin-prime-pairs-occuring-in-an-interval-a-b

Answer (score 3):

It is a well-known conjecture that the number of of twin primes below $n$ is asymptotically equal to 
`\[2C_2 \frac{n}{(\log n)^2}\]` with $C_2 = 0.66...$ (the value of a certain infinite product). 
See eg this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime that also mentions Brun's upper bound which is perhaps what you refer to.

Comment: There is a typo:it should be 2*C_2,not C_2

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(N)$ be the number of known twin primes up to $N$. Then I'm afraid the only known lower bound for the number of twin primes up to $N$ is $f(N)$. If no one has ever looked to see whether there are any twin primes between, say, $e^{1000}$ and $e^{2000}$, then for all we know there aren't any.

Comment: And, it's worth adding, the fact that this is the only known lower bound isn't because nobody has tried. All modern approaches to proving the twin prime conjecture aim for a quantitative lower bound of the type you describe.

Comment: Greg, I was tempted to quibble this comment. But then it occurred to me that there really *aren't* any modern approaches to the twin prime conjecture. One could imagine an approach using nonstandard analysis, though, which would give no quantitative lower bounds.



Comment: @Ben: yeah, my comment is vague enough to be obviously false (or possibly obviously true, if truly vague). I guess I was trying to communicate to the OP that his idea is part of the "standard" approach to the problem.